# Address of the page depending on the value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a serious problem. I want to add two fields to this form "male" and "female" and assign them to separate addresses, eg for "female" htp://female.com and for the male "htp://male.com". So if you choose the "Category1" and check field "female" you will be redirected to the page "htp://female.com/Category1" and if you check field "male" and "Category1" you will be redirected to the page "htp://male.com/Category1"

```
function Open() {
  var url=document.redirect.selection.value
  document.location.href=url 
}

<form name="redirect">
    <select name="selection">
        <option value="/category1">Category1</option>
        <option value="/category2">Category2</option>
    </select>
    <input type=button value="Go!" onClick="Open();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quickshot to outline a possible solution. So if i understand you correctly you're looking for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZpMFY/show/

```
<script>
    function Open() {
        var category = document.redirect.selection.value,
            domain = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value;;

        document.location.href= domain + category;
    }
</script>

<form name="redirect">
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="http://male.com" checked>Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="http://female.com">Female
    </p>     

    <select name="selection">
        <option value="/category1">Category1</option>
        <option value="/category2">Category2</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" value="Go!" onclick="Open();">
</form>
```

You should note that [.queryselector()](http://bit.ly/M5TBQz) works only in IE8 and UP

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$('select').change(function(){
   location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
})
```